# Implementing mobFox causes crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ads

Just trying to implement mobFox into my app, but having trouble to make it run. I suspect that it is because of my general approach not to use IB at all, because the sample code works just fine.

After run it is pointing to the line

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"UntitledAppDelegate");
```

which is in my main.m,

with this as result

```
2011-04-18 16:07:48.000 BinTeeth[10141:bf07] -[NSCFString md5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x622ef40
2011-04-18 16:07:48.001 BinTeeth[10141:bf07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString md5]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x622ef40'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x014845a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015d8313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x014860bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x013f5966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x013f5522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   BinTeeth                            0x0002d90f -[MobFoxBannerView asyncRequestAdWithPublisherId:] + 177
    6   Foundation                          0x00670cf4 -[NSThread main] + 81
    7   Foundation                          0x00670c80 __NSThread__main__ + 1387
    8   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9758c85d _pthread_start + 345
    9   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9758c6e2 thread_start + 34
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

any help would be appreciated, I have tried many things, but nothing really looks loke solution for me so far

tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the linker-flags as described in the SDK documentation?

Best

Comment: Ok, actually first I have put there -objC and was wandering WTH...o mine...-ObjC is right..thank you to remind me to check again. :)

Comment: also make sure you have set both debug AND release to -ObjC that was my mistake...... only had debug so it was working fine while debuging but as soon as I tryed it in instruments it crashed! guess this is only for Xcode 4